# Using AWS EC2 API (https) with EC2 Launch Templates - The parameter LaunchTemplate is not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-ec2, https, postman

I am extremely new with APIs and can not figure this out.

I have a use case where I want to call the AWS EC2 Rest API over https to start an instance from a  Launch Template. I am using "RunInstances" [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) to attempt this. I have scrolled through the document and included all of the required parameters.

I then added "ImageId" to the test and got a good run (no issues with authentication, etc). The default instance was created.

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get the API to accept the "LaunchTemplate" option. I either get "The parameter LaunchTemplate is not recognized" or a "400 - bad request" error.

In postman I have:
[Postman Screenshot with the RunInstances call set up and the full URL visable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqCKE.png)

This is the link to the "LaunchTemplateSpecification" object documentation (linked from 1 also) [3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_LaunchTemplateSpecification.html)

Can someone help me figure out how to construct the API request for the "LaunchTemplate" parameter?

Also, my web searches have not revealed HTTPS (web url) examples only CLI examples (none for this paramater in the docs either). If someone found a link that I could not, please send it my way.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer but have you considered the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html)?  In the [EC2 run-instances](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) command there are multiple references to launch templates.  As a general statement I use either the CLI or the SDK's.  For example, the Java SDK for [runInstances](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#runInstances(java.util.function.Consumer)) takes a class that allows you to specify a LaunchTemplate.

Comment: I wish it was that simple! I have built systems with the CLI and prefer that. However, I am stuck having to develop a third-party system (FileMaker) that only really supports curl for this type of interaction. I could set things to a file (code a .sh file or use other means) and then run the file or interact with files in the OS but then I sacrifice some of the abilities that I could build in with a more direct route like what I have described above. Many references to Launch Templates are in the Linked docs also... I figured I was just not knowledgeable enough yet.

Comment: If you look at the first link you gave `LaunchTemplate` is an object of type `LaunchTemplateSpecification`, not the name of the template.  I believe you want `LaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateName` in your example.

Comment: @stdunbar Substituting `LaunchTemplate` with `LaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateName` in the postman screenshot attached to the question yields the error: "The parameter LaunchTemplate is not recognized". I have wondered if their docs are wrong, but surely Amazon could do better... I wonder if i should create a support task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stdunbar was correct so far as the `LaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateName` parameter was concerned.

I submitted a case to AWS support and received a response. I was missing a "version" parameter.

The correct parameter set is as follows:

```
https://us-east-1.ec2.amazonaws.com/?
   Action=RunInstances&
   MaxCount=1&
   MinCount=1&
   LaunchTemplate.LaunchTemplateName=Testing-Template&
   Version=2016-11-15
```

Here is an updated Image of Postman (for learners like me) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQht.png)